# Spring Boot fail to start with using @EnableBinding and zkNodes not available

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have consumer with 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=KAFKA_URL
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=ZKNODE_URL

If I try to run spring boot consumer app and zkNode is not up, entire spring boot app fails to start:
rg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer: 
...
Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000

My question is:
 how to overcome this and prevent entire app to crash and also how to periodically retry to connect?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is being tracked in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/12)